# Is it possible to remove AM/PM button from TimePicker?

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to show *24 hours* clock instead *12 hours* using TimePicker,and I dont need the AM/PM buton, Simply want to show 24 hours clock.

Is this possible?

I used `setIs24HourView(true)` but it is is not working.

Suggest me How can I show 24 hours clock?

Comment: Just curious, but why does it need to be in the layout and not in the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Have you tried setting setIs24HourView?](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29)

If you just need use the NumberPicker widget in other abnormal ways:

There is a NumberPicker widget in Android, but it is a private API.  [This guy pulled out the code](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5) such that you can drop it into any project.

[Here is an example of how I used it for tax rates:](http://code.google.com/p/tippytipper/source/browse/trunk/Tippy%20Tipper%20Library/src/net/mandaria/tippytipperlibrary/preferences/DecimalPreference.java)

[image]

Comment: i prefeer to use timepicker, i need bassically to call "setIs24HourView(true)" from the layout, not from the java code.

it is possible?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible, I can't find it in the documentation :/

Comment: ouch well i will wait if someone know it

Comment: (example link is dead...)  Could you post how you did the double picker control separated by a decimal? That's pretty neat.

Comment: @pmont new link here: http://code.google.com/p/tippytipper/source/browse/trunk/Tippy%20Tipper%20Library/src/net/mandaria/tippytipperlibrary/preferences/DecimalPreference.java I recently migrated code into a library project. Will update answer too.

Answer (score 6):

I've experienced the same problem but solved it by doing the `setIs24HourView` in the `onCreate` call for the activity..

Answer (score 2):

You must call setIs24HourView function and send true for that.
when time picker are in 24 mode AM/PM will be disappear.

```
TimePicker tpHourMin = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
tpHourMin.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overrite the

```
public void onTimeChanged (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) 
method of TimePickerDialog to completely remove AM/PM:

class MyTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {
    MyTimePickerDialog(Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
    }
@Override
public void onTimeChanged (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // to prevent the dialog from changing the title which by default contains AM/PM
}
}
```

Here is how to use it

```
MyTimePickerDialog dialog = new MyTimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, 
                        true /*DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())*/);
dialog.setTitle("Set Time");
```